# Change browser proxy settings from Python in Ubintu?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, firefox, browser

Is there any way to change the firefox and chrome proxy through a python script.
System is Ubuntu or any other linux distro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the browser settings as set the proxy as system proxy.

Then your python script will be

```
import os

os.system('export http://<your proxy>:<your port>/')
os.system('export https://<your proxy>:<your port>/')
```

This will set the system proxy as your proxy and hence your browser will be using your system proxy.

Comment: Thanks .Is there any way so that it works in a way ,keeping the browser proxy as no proxy